# How use psycopg2.sql.Identifier as a single quotes?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I get error when creating function to create table using postgresql database

```
def create_table(tb_names, cursor):

cursor.execute(sql.SQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {}").format(sql.Identifier(tb_names)))
cursor.execute(sql.SQL("""CREATE TABLE {}(
                        id SERIAL,
                        PRIMARY KEY (id))
                """).format(sql.Identifier(tb_names)))
cursor.execute(sql.SQL("SELECT AddGeometryColumn({}, 'geom', 3375, 'POLYGON', 2)").format(sql.Identifier(tb_names)))
cursor.execute(sql.SQL("CREATE INDEX geomIndex ON {} USING GIST 

(geom)").format(sql.Identifier(tb_names)))

create_table(tb_names="test_data1", cursor=cur)
```

```
error:
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: column "test_data1" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT AddGeometryColumn("test_data1", 'geom', 3375, 'POLYGO...
```

Any idea how to solve it?

How to pass variable as a single quote?

Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 2):

... pass it as a regular parameter to `execute`?

The point of `sql.Identifier` is to apply *identifier* quoting rules when the string is an *identitfier* to inject in the query. That is how it's used in the first, second and last query but in the third it looks to be a regular parameter, why are you quoting and injecting it as an identifier?

Comment: Because i think sql.Identifier is the only way to pass the variable into sql syntax. Passing parameter with ("SELECT AddGeometryColumn(%s, 'geom', 3375, 'POLYGON', 2)", (test_data1)) is working, but how to change test_data1 with my variable?

Comment: "("SELECT AddGeometryColumn(%s, 'geom', 3375, 'POLYGON', 2)", (test_data1)) is working" I doubt that. Read the psycopg2 documentation and learn to use the library. The way to perform an SQL query is [`cursor.execute(query, vars)`](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.execute) where vars is a sequence or mapping, so this should be `cursor.execute("select ...", [test_data1])` ensuring proper escape & interpolation, but [does not work for situations where you need to vary non-value components of the SQL query](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html) hence `sql.Identifier` for that.

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

cursor.execute("SELECT AddGeometryColumn(%s, 'geom', 3375, 'POLYGON', 2)", [tb_names])

Just learn how to passing a regular parameter using my variable. :)